# Remove every other elements of a list

Tags: c#, list

I have list that is guaranteed to contain sequential pairs of identical elements. Is there a way to remove half of repeating values in a list (any one element of each pair)?

Example #1:

Take:

```
{2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5}
```

And return:

```
{2, 2 , 5}
```

Example #2:

Take:

```
{8, 8, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1}
```

And return:

```
{8, 1, 5, 1}
```

There is no need to verify if elements actually comes in pairs.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where is you code?

Comment: does same pairs always occur consecutively?

Comment: What you expect to see from the list {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5} ??

Comment: Yes They Will always be in pairs

Comment: Who voted to close this question as "too broad"? It seems fairly specific to me.

Comment: @Enigmativity "too broad" was voted as one of acceptable reason for "plz give me teh codez"/"do my homework" questions (i.e. [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250867/close-reason-suggestion-closing-a-question-where-the-asker-wants-others-to-do-h))... so not exactly surprising that someone voted that way on question showing comparable amount of effort to find solution (or even clarify the problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the sequence is guaranteed to be made of consecutive pairs, then this works:

```
values.Where((x, n) => n % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: Will Do, Just Have To Wait A Little Bit

Comment: +1. Enigmativity, Would you mind editing question into better shape to match now accepted answer?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I'm not following you - what needs to change in the question?